# Is it possible to view source code of assembly? If yes then How?

Tags: asp.net, dll, assemblies

I m using a assembly EventCalender. The ddl is EventCalender.dll. I copied this assembly from existing application. It provides customized functionality to calender. I want to see the code of that dll and want to change some functionality of it. How it will be possible..? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

If the dll is written in .NET you can view the code using [the .NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/).

Answer (score 2):

Try lutz roeders 'Reflector' tool

http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/

Answer (score 1):

I think this [link](http://www.builderau.com.au/program/asp/soa/Look-inside-NET-DLL-files-with-Reflector/0,339028371,339287377,00.htm) will help you. You can do it using Reflector.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to view the IL code of the DLL, you can use ILDASM. If you want to convert it back to VB.NET or C#, use Reflector as the previous answers have suggested. One of the plugins allows you to extract all class files within the assembly to a single folder.

However, one point that others haven't addressed is that if you want to change the functionality, you **will** need to recompile the library after resolving all external references.